# View get unhide automatically in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a view on interface & reducing its height on click of a button with uianimation.Below is the code for the animation

```
@IBAction func filterClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    STF_Search.resignFirstResponder()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations:{

        if(self.isFilter==false){

            self.filterView.frame=CGRectMake(0,117,self.view.frame.size.width,50)
            self.STVRA.frame=CGRectMake(0, 168,self.STVRA.frame.size.width,self.STVRA.frame.size.height)
            self.isFilter=true
        }
        else{

            self.filterView.frame=CGRectMake(0,117,self.view.frame.size.width,0)
            self.tableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 117,self.STVRA.frame.size.width,self.STVRA.frame.size.height)
            self.dateTo="nil"
            self.dateFrom="nil"
            self.isControlls(true)
            self.isFilter=false
        }
    }
        ,completion: {(_) -> Void in

            if(self.isFilter==true){

                self.isControlls(false)
            }
            else{

             self.callRAListWebApi()

            }
    })
}
```

Code working perfectly if I don't call the method "self.callRAListWebApi()" on the other hand in above scenario when execution of this methods complete the "filterView" gets into its default height-> 50 which is not supposed as per the logic it should be "0"
("callRAListWebApi" is a method where I am hitting a web api & getting some json response)
I cant understand this unusual behaviour of "filter view" of coming in its original height.I have checked everything there is no clue.

Comment: Are you using constraints and auto layout?  What does `callRAListWebApi` do?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am using auto layout , callRAListWebApi is a method to hit a web api & collect its json response

Comment: If you are using auto layout then you need to manipulate the constraints not the frame directly. You can create an IBOutlet for the constraint

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry didnt get "create an IBOutlet for the constraint "

Comment: @Paulw11 do you think the problem is because of frame?

Comment: Yes, if you manipulate the frame but then do something to cause the view to be refreshed then auto layout will reset the frame.  If you have a constraint for, say, an objects height then you can create an `IBOutlet` for the height `NSLayoutConstraint` and then link that IBOutlet to the constraint in your storyboard just as you would with a `UITextField` or `UILabel`.  Then you can animate the change to the constraints `constant` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `autolayout` of the view , as the problem is because you are directly changing the frames.